# How to display labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

This is probably one of the most asked questions for ggplot but I did not find an answer that worked for me. It seems like whatever I doo, the colour-labels do not show up on my graph.

(I also can't find a description of all the elements of a ggplot and one of my problems is that I don't know what it's called.)

[image: img]

data

```
veloaua$CantonCode,veloaua$time
BE,21:00
SG,12:00
JU,15:00
SO,9:00
ZH,7:00
ZG,8:00
BE,13:00
BE,13:00
AG,18:00
ZH,15:00
BS,16:00
BS,8:00
BS,13:00
BS,14:00
BS,10:00
BS,17:00
BS,14:00
BS,12:00
BS,11:00
BS,18:00
```

What I wrote so far.

```
ggplot(data = veloaua[veloaua$CantonCode == "BS",], aes(x = as.POSIXct(time,format="%H:%M"), 
                                                                    y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), , colour = "blue") +
  geom_histogram(bins = 24,
                 fill= "blue", 
                 alpha=0.3,
                 colour = "black") +
  #Die Daten für die gesamte Schweiz lege ich drüber
  geom_histogram(data = veloaua, 
                 aes(x = as.POSIXct(veloaua$time,format="%H:%M"), y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), colour = "grey"),
                 bins = 24,
                 fill= "grey", 
                 alpha=0.3,
                 colour="#303030",
                 linetype="dashed") +
  scale_colour_manual("", 
                      breaks = c("cba", "abc"),
                      values = c("red", "green"))+
  #scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  #labs(x ="Zeitpunkt", y ="Anteil",  colour = "kanton")+
  ggtitle("Zu dieser Uhrzeit gab es die meisten Unfälle")
```

Comment: Could you be explicit about what you are expecting from the labels? Do you wish the legend key (boxes) to be filled with a colour? If you are struggling with ggplot2 terminology and find the documentation   is not that helpful there are many resources on-line none the least [ggplot2: elegant graphics for data analysis](https://ggplot2-book.org)

Comment: I recommend you check out the examples on the great website http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/32-r-graphics-essentials/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a legend you have to map on aesthetics, move `fill="blue"` (and `"grey"`) inside aes(). Note that "blue" is just a label or placeholder. To set or assign a color to this label make use of `scale_fill_manual`. Besides the colors for each label you could assign a nice label for the legend via the `labels` argument of `scale_fill_manual`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = veloaua[veloaua$CantonCode == "BS", ], aes(
  x = as.POSIXct(time, format = "%H:%M"),
  y = (..count..) / sum(..count..)
)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = "blue"),
    bins = 24,
    alpha = 0.3,
    colour = "black"
  ) +
  geom_histogram(
    data = veloaua,
    aes(x = as.POSIXct(veloaua$time, format = "%H:%M"), y = (..count..) / sum(..count..), fill = "grey"),
    bins = 24,
    alpha = 0.3,
    colour = "#303030",
    linetype = "dashed"
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c(blue = "blue", grey = "grey"),
    labels = c(blue = "blue label", grey = "grey label")
  ) +
  ggtitle("Zu dieser Uhrzeit gab es die meisten Unfälle")
#> Warning: Use of `veloaua$time` is discouraged. Use `time` instead.
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
veloaua <- structure(list(CantonCode = c(
  "BE", "SG", "JU", "SO", "ZH", "ZG",
  "BE", "BE", "AG", "ZH", "BS", "BS", "BS", "BS", "BS", "BS", "BS",
  "BS", "BS", "BS"
), time = c(
  "21:00", "12:00", "15:00", "9:00",
  "7:00", "8:00", "13:00", "13:00", "18:00", "15:00", "16:00",
  "8:00", "13:00", "14:00", "10:00", "17:00", "14:00", "12:00",
  "11:00", "18:00"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```